# How to refresh a local XML File?

Tags: xml, ios

Iam developing an iPhone Application which is parsing a local XML File. How can I refresh (overwrite) this XML on the iPhone, if my XML File on the Webserver has been changed.

The XML File is really small (30 KB).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to copy the XML file to the user home folder and then update it there.

Comment: Sorry I dont know much about the File System in iOs. Is the documents folder the same? Is there any Sample Code available ?

Comment: Ah yes, the exact name for it was the Documents folder. YOu can probably get started with the FS documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH1-SW1

Comment: Don’t know one online, but the Stanford iOS programming video course in iTunesU had an introduction to it.

Answer (score 0):

If it works like Flash, then appending a random variable, or a timestamp, to the end of the path to the XML file might make iOS refresh it. As in "[path to file]/myXMLfile.xml?x=123456"